# making server in node.js simple hello world

Tags: cygwin, node.js

I had installed node by following article https://github.com/ry/node/wiki/Building-node.js-on-Cygwin-%28Windows%29

Now i had made a test.js file in c:/cygwin/home/adminstrator/test.js  here my node folder is present.

My test.js file is

```
var sys = require("sys"),  
    http = require("http");  

 http.createServer(function(request, response) {  
     response.sendHeader(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});  
     response.write("Hello World!");  
     response.close();  
 }).listen(8080);  

 sys.puts("Server running at http://localhost:8080/");
```

But in browser if run localhost:8080 or 8.8.8.8:8080 the content is not displaying ("hello world ")

Please suggest what should i do ?

**Edit**  Error while running command

```
$ node /home/Administrator/test.js
Server running at http://localhost:8080/

/home/Administrator/test.js:5
     response.sendHeader(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
              ^
TypeError: Object #<a ServerResponse> has no method 'sendHeader'
    at Server.<anonymous> (/home/Administrator/test.js:5:15)
    at Server.emit (events.js:27:15)
    at HTTPParser.onIncoming (http.js:871:14)
    at HTTPParser.onHeadersComplete (http.js:88:31)
    at Stream.ondata (http.js:792:22)
    at Stream._onReadable (net.js:762:27)
    at IOWatcher.onReadable [as callback] (net.js:276:10)
```

Comment: Have you started node.js using `node /home/adminstrator/test.js` command from cygwin console?

Comment: @actual if i do node test.js it show the output of  sys.puts("Output")  funciton. but how to run in browser respose.write ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The methods `.sendHeader()` and `.close()` don't exist. You wan't `.writeHead()` and `.end()` instead.

Reference: http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.3.7/api/http.html#http.ServerResponse

Comment: @Box9  But how to open in browser ?

Comment: @Rahul, sorry I missed that part. In cygwin type: `node /home/administrator/test.js`, then direct your browser to `localhost:8080`.

Comment: @Rahul, no, apache is completely different. You say that you see the message "Server running at..." in Cygwin? Do you see anything else? (Both before and after you put "localhost:8080" into your browser.

Comment: @Rahul, that's because sendHeader doesn't exist either. I've updated my answer with the correct method, but please check the documentation I linked to!